# post api call using Vue js axios dose not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i would like to fetch data from api to list most liked products i use Post request with headers and bodies but i tried some vue js and axios code but it is not working . following is the Api response in Postman

https://anotepad.com/notes/gr6w67

following is my frontend code

```js
<script>
        new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null,
   results:''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
   axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: url+'api/getallproducts',
  data: {
  language_id:1,
       type:'most liked1',
     page_number:1,
  },
   headers: {
        
        "consumer-key": consumer_key, 
  "consumer-secret": consumer_secret, 
  "consumer-nonce": 2223344, 
  "consumer-device-id": consumer_device_id,  
    },
.then(response => {console.log(response.product_data.product_id)
//.then(response => {console.log(data)
 //alert(response);
});
   
   }
})
  })     
        </script>
```

```html
<div id="app" class="ltabs-items-inner ltabs-slider">


<template v-for="result in results">
<div class="row">
 <div class="ltabs-item">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 
    <div class="item-inner product-layout transition product-grid">
      <div class="product-item-container">
      
        <div class="left-block">
          <div class="product-image-container second_img"> <a href="#!" target="_self" title="Pastrami bacon"> <img  src="{{ asset('public/frontend/qshopee')}}/image/catalog/demo/product/320/9.jpg" class="img-1 img-responsive" alt="Pastrami bacon"> <img  src="{{ asset('public/frontend/qshopee')}}/image/catalog/demo/product/320/9.jpg" class="img-2 img-responsive" alt="Pastrami bacon"> </a> </div>
          <div class="button-group so-quickview cartinfo--left">
            <button type="button" class="addToCart btn-button" title="Add to cart" onClick="cart.add('60 ');"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> <span>Add to cart </span> </button>
            <button type="button" class="wishlist btn-button" title="Add to Wish List" onClick="wishlist.add('60');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span>Add to Wish List</span> </button>
            <button type="button" class="compare btn-button" title="Compare this Product " onClick="compare.add('60');"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i><span>Compare this Product</span> </button>
            <!--quickview--> 
            <a class="iframe-link btn-button quickview quickview_handler visible-lg" href="quickview.html" title="Quick view" data-fancybox-type="iframe"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span>Quick view</span></a> 
            <!--end quickview--> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-block">
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="rating"> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> </div>
            <h4><a href="#!" title="Pastrami bacon" target="_self">Product Name</a></h4>
            
            
             <div class="price"> <span class="price-new">$1000</span>
                                                                <span class="price-old">$1500 </span>
                                                            </div>

             
             
                                        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  </template>
  
  

</div>
```

following is Api postman response  :https://anotepad.com/notes/gr6w67

Comment: looks like the request is working but the response is encoded

Comment: Your frontend code is incomplete. Please update the question to show the full context of the axios call.